# This command can only be used by root

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu 16 and I'd like to add a neo4j package.
I tried in 3 ways all leading to the same error.

These are my attempts:

```
wget -O - http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | apt-key add -

sudo wget -O - http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | apt-key add -

sudo -i wget -O - http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | apt-key add -
```

But I always get this error message:

```
ERROR: This command can only be used by root.
--2016-11-04  http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key
Resolving debian.neo4j.org (debian.neo4j.org)... 52.0.233.188
Connecting to debian.neo4j.org (debian.neo4j.org)|52.0.233.188|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4791 (4,7K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                     0%[                    ]       0  --.-KB/s    in 0s      


Cannot write to ‘-’ (Broken pipe).
```

Comment: I think this question will be better suited here: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 24):

It's the second part of the command that needs to be executed as `root`.

```
sudo wget -O - http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Not super elegant, but it works :)

Comment: There is no need to run `wget` as root. Try `wget -O - http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04, GO through below steps & get out of rid
First restart your pc, and press the **SHIFT key or ESC** while Ubuntu is booting.
This will bring you up the boot menu.

Select Advanced Options.
Select your OS version in (recovery mode), and press Enter Key.
Ex : Ubuntu 14.04 **(recovery mode)**
It will bring you up another screen. Now select “Drop to root shell prompt” and press Enter.
It will load a command line at the bottom of the screen.

Now run each of the following commands.

```
mount -o remount,rw /

mount –all

chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo

chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo

restart
```